# When I use Filtered_tg in R. The console show this error :- Error in arrange(filtered_tg, len) : could not find function "arrange"

Tags: google-analytics, data-science, data-analysis

[Error show in Rstdio I try to fix it but and watch video in youtube but I can't found where is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nmgt.png)

I code this:-

```
data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowth)

filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
View(filtered_tg)
arrange(filtered_tg, len)
arrange(filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5),len)
```

output :-

```
View(filtered_tg)
Error in View : object 'filtered_tg' not found
> View(filter_tg)
Error in View : object 'filter_tg' not found
> View(filtered_tg)
Error in View : object 'filtered_tg' not found
> View(filtered_tg)
Error in View : object 'filtered_tg' not found
> arrange(filtered_tg, len)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is **dplyr** library missing at the top of your code, `filter()` and `arrange()` functions are from **dplyr** library. Here is how it works on my side:

```
> library(dplyr)
> 
> data("ToothGrowth")
> View(ToothGrowth)
> 
> filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
> View(filtered_tg)
> arrange(filtered_tg, len)
len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2   5.2   VC  0.5
3   5.8   VC  0.5
...
18 16.5   OJ  0.5
19 17.6   OJ  0.5
20 21.5   OJ  0.5
> arrange(filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5),len)
len supp dose
1   4.2   VC  0.5
2   5.2   VC  0.5
3   5.8   VC  0.5
...
18 16.5   OJ  0.5
19 17.6   OJ  0.5
20 21.5   OJ  0.5
```